# Code seems to just freeze after processing ~15 million lines

Tags: csv, io, racket

The following function seems to just stop after some time when run on a file with ~21 million lines. It prints up to 15520000 and then stops. I tested it with smaller files and it works fine in that case.

```
#lang racket

(define (read-csv name)
  (define item-hash (make-hash))
  (define user-hash (make-hash))
  (define list-hash (make-hash))
  (define item-number 0)
  (define user-number 0)
  (define n 0)

  (with-input-from-file name
    (thunk
     (for ([line (in-lines)])
       (define row (string-split line ","))
       (match-define (list user item score) row)
       (when (= item-number
                (hash-ref! item-hash item item-number))
         (set! item-number (+ 1 item-number)))
       (when (= user-number
                (hash-ref! user-hash user user-number))
         (set! user-number (+ 1 user-number)))

       (when (= 0(modulo n 10000))
         (display n)
         (display "\n"))
       (set! n (+ 1 n))

       (let ([l (hash-ref! list-hash user '())])
         (hash-set! list-hash user (cons (cons item score) l))))))

  (list item-hash user-hash list-hash))
```

Comment: Without knowing anything about racket, I'd say you ran out of allocated memory

Comment: Are you getting an error message or does it just hang?

Comment: Late in the game but could you give us a few sample lines of input ? What is the range of the values ? I'd like to get a feel of how often users are repeated.